# Terminology for Linear Programs without Objective Functions

Tags: linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization, integer-programming, satisfiability

I have a linear program without an objective function. That is, I am looking for a feasible solution to a given set of linear constraints. Is there a specific term for such problems? Likewise, for integer linear programs also, is there a precise term? How would it be different from a SAT/SMT problem?

Comment: I would call it the (integer) feasibility problem for a polyhedron